# The icon from Bootstrap css file not loaded when offline

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have datetime picker, The problem is no icon appear in the page. But if I disable line (comment out) from local bootstrap.css then add hyperlink bootstrap.css from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css its worked perfectly. So why? I want to local css file that I used to offline, I dont want to online css rendering.
Here my code :

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
               format : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So its work if with this line,

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I was downloaded that css then I used for offline but it not working. Please Help
Thank you,

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same version of bootstrap css and js.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Okay it solved. Many thanks! I was placed all of bootstrap master. But I dont know what the list folder is just needed from all folder? But is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all the contents of bootstrap package in the folder including fonts provided by bootstrap

bootstrap folder structure is like

```
    bootstrap/
    ├── css/
    │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
    ├── js/
    │   ├── bootstrap.js
    │   └── bootstrap.min.js
    └── fonts/
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

you have not included the `Font` folder. Just Download the whole whole bootstrap package from there official site and keep the folder structure same and then include the css file as

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Hi I was added that file but not working. Finnaly I copied all of master folder bootstrap and it working, but I realy dont know what exactly folder is needed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you not only download the css stylesheet but also the glypicons included with it, when you donwload boostrap, it comes with a fonts folder, put that folder  in the same directory as the boostrap css.